# Biblatex: article with two printed references section, plus citing after

Tags: biblatex

I have an article which must have two references section. I used `biblatex` to do that. In order for the numbered references to continue from one section to the next, I enabled the global option `defernumbers=true`, and used `resetnumbers=false` for the second reference section.

I also have a third section, with citations that have already appeared in the first or second reference sections. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@misc{paper1,
    author={name1},
    title={title1},
    year={2021}
}

@misc{paper2,
    author={name2},
    title={title2},
    year={2021}
}

@misc{paper3,
    author={name3},
    title={title3},
    year={2021}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\section{Section One}
Section one citations: \cite{paper1,paper2}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\section{Section Two}
Section two citations: \cite{paper3}
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=false]
\end{refsection}

\section{Section Three}
Second three citations: \cite{paper2}

\end{document}
```

The rendered PDF is shown below:

[image: Article preview]

My questions are:

1. Why the second reference section starts numbering from 1 rather than 3? (Note `defernumbers=true` and `resetnumbers=false`, and I cleared every temporary file like `.aux` and recompiled multiple times.)
2. How to make the citation in the third section to appear correctly?

**Edit:** This is what I want to achieve (differences from the above image are depicted in red):

[image: Target output]

Comment: `refsection`s are kept *completely* separate from each other: In particular the numbering in each refsection starts from 1 and entries. In your example section 1 and 2 have completely separate and independent bibliographies. Section 3 has no bibliography at all, because you use `defernumbers` you get a 0. I don't quite understand which output you want to achieve and why, so I can't offer a solution now. All I can say at the moment is that `refsegment`s are an alternative to `refsection`s and are not kept separate. This may or may not help.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried `refsegments` as you suggested, but I didn't achieved what I wanted. For clarification, I edited the question and added an image depicting what I want to reach at.

Comment: It is possible to achieve the result you want with `refsegment`s, but it would be great if you could not only show an example of the output you want, but explained the principle behind the output you want (why do you need this output?). There might be several ways to obtain the same result in this example, but those ways might scale differently and produce different results in different (larger) setups.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/00a5dcd82545109ac1aa909f043cb67a should produce the output that you want in the MWE, but it does not scale terribly well if you want to extend this to more than two sections.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks, your MWE works as expected. As to why I need this, it's a PDF file I want to mimic. The PDF file is provided by an external entity, and I should follow it as template. The first section is a review of the state of the art, followed by references. The second section is a review of own previous work (followed by references). The third section is suggestions for future work, and may refer to papers in the first two sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refsection`s are always kept completely separate and independent from each other (and so is the numbering in each `refsection`), so there is no official way to not reset the count in a new `refsection`.

You may want to try `refsegment`s, which are not kept separate.

The following gives the desired result in the MWE but may or may not scale well enough for your actual application.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\defbibfilter{notsegmentOne}{not segment=1}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{paper1,
  author = {name1},
  title  = {title1},
  year   = {2021},
}
@misc{paper2,
  author = {name2},
  title  = {title2},
  year   = {2021},
}
@misc{paper3,
  author = {name3},
  title  = {title3},
  year   = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
Section one citations: \cite{paper1,paper2}
\printbibliography[filter=notsegmentOne]

\begin{refsegment}
\section{Section Two}
Section two citations: \cite{paper3}
\printbibliography[segment=1]
\end{refsegment}

\section{Section Three}
Second three citations: \cite{paper2}

\end{document}
```

[image: citations 1 and 2 in section 1, 3 in section 2 and then again 2 in section 3]